# List Comprehensions in Python to compute minimum and maximum values of a list

Tags: python, list, max, list-comprehension, min

i have the following code to compute minimum and maximum values of a list in order to save memory efficiency

```
x_min = float('+inf')
x_max = float('-inf')

for p in points_in_list:
    x_min = min(x_min, p)
    x_max = max(x_max, p)
```

where points_in_list is a (large) list of numbers. I wish to know if there is a method to compute with a List Comprehensions the min and max value and saving the memory.

Comment: what does a point in points_in_list look like? which attribute does it have?

Comment: Have you tried `min(points_in_list)` and `max(points_in_list)`? No list comprehension needed here.

Comment: it's a really large list (over 6 milions of values) as points_in_list = [1,3,6,79,80,...,76] of number

Comment: Calling `min` or `max` on a huge list isn't going to produce memory problems. Why would it? Were you under the impression that doing so would require making a copy of the entire list?

Comment: Why do you think a list comprehension would use less memory than `min`?

Comment: List comprehensions produce *lists*, while you want to compute single values *from* lists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a big fan of generators and comprehensions, but in this case it seems they are not the right way to go, because:

1. You want to compute the `min` and the `max` of the list
2. Your list is huge

If you wanted to calculate only one of the `min` or `max`, you could just use the min/max function on it. But since you want both, you would have to loop over the list twice to extract first the min and then the max. I.e. something like this:

```
x_min = min(points)
x_max = max(points)
```

Let's play with some some timings. First calling both min and max on the list:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def with_gens(l):
...     return min(l), max(l)
...
>>> timeit.timeit('with_gens(range(6000000))', 'from __main__ import with_gens', number=5)
1.7451060887015188
```

and now looping only once, using you code:

```
>>> def with_loop2(l):
...     x_max = float('+inf')
...     x_min = float('-inf')
...     for el in l:
...         x_min = min(x_min, el)
...         x_max = max(x_max, el)
...     return x_min, x_max
...
>>> timeit.timeit('with_loop2(range(6000000))', 'from __main__ import with_loop2', number=5)
11.636076105071083
```

Crazy, huh?

There is no memory problem at all with this approach. However, it sets the `x_max` and `x_min` in each loop, which is actually an unnecessary waste: you only want to reset the variable when you have found a bigger/smaller value. We can easily address this.

So... let's try looping only once, but avoiding unnecessary resettings.

```
>>> def with_loop(l):
...     x_min = float('-inf')
...     x_max = float('+inf')
...     for el in l:
...         if el < x_min:
...             x_min = el
...         elif el > x_max:
...             x_max = el
...     return x_min, x_max
...
>>> timeit.timeit('with_loop(range(6000000))', 'from __main__ import with_loop', number=5)
3.961046726963332
```

**OH SURPRISE**

It seems while the algorithm of looping only once is on the paper more efficient, it is beaten by the inner optimization of `min` and `max`. Moreover, the difference between setting the var in each loop and only when necessary is huge. *You never stop learning*.

Comment: might also be interesting to run the tests with a random range of numbers (rather than a sorted list where x_max will be reassigned each time, and x_min is never reassigned) and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 8):

Suppose a point has two attributes, `x` and `y`, then you can use

`x_min = min(p['x'] for p in points_in_list)` to calculate the min of x

An example:

```
>>> a = {'x': 10, 'y':10}
>>> b = {'x': 5, 'y':20}
>>> c = {'x': 50, 'y':50}
>>> points_in_list = [a,b,c]
>>> points_in_list
[{'y': 10, 'x': 10}, {'y': 20, 'x': 5}, {'y': 50, 'x': 50}]
>>> x_min = min(p['x'] for p in points_in_list)
>>> x_min
5
```

Comment: nice, what would be the time complexity of the min(p['x'] for p in points_in_list), is it O(N) assuming there are N items in points_in_list? And what's in the min function as parameter, is it considered a list (i.e. p['x'] for p in points_in_list) ?